Trouble with randomizing enemies in SFML. Newbie question
I tried making a SFML C++ 2D space shooter game. So I've made a game following a guideline which used basic shapes for enemies. Instead, I tried to put textures and sprites into them. It worked correctly and sprite appeared on the screen, but when I got to randomizing spawn of enemies on screen, I got into a problem of enemy still spawning on the left corner of the screen. Would love some insight on the problem.
**
My CPP file:**
#include "Game.h"

using namespace sf;

//конструктор и деструктор
Game::Game()
{
this->initWindow();
this->initTextures();
this->initPlayer();
this->initEnemies();
}

Game::~Game()
{
delete this->window;
delete this->player;

    for (auto &i : this->textures) {
        delete i.second;
    }
    for (auto &i : this->enemies) {
        delete i;
    }

}

void Game::initEnemies() {
this->spawnTimerMax = 20.f;
this->spawnTimer = this->spawnTimerMax;
}

void Game::updateEnemies() {
this->spawnTimer += 0.5f;
if (this->spawnTimer >= spawnTimerMax) {
this->enemies.push_back(new Enemy(rand() % 1920, rand() % 1080));
this->spawnTimer = 0.f;
}

    for (auto *enemy : this->enemies) {
        enemy->update();
    }

}

void Game::update() {
this->updatePollEvents();
this->updateInput();
this->player-\>update();
this->updateBullets();
this->updateEnemies();
}

void Game::render() {
this->window->clear());

    this->player->render(*this->window);
    
    for (auto &enemy : this->enemies) {
        enemy->render(*this->window);
    }
    
    this->window->display();

}

**My header file Game.h:**

#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include "Player.h"
#include "Bullet.h"
#include "Enemy.h"

using namespace sf;

class Game
{
    private:
    RenderWindow* window;

    float spawnTimer;
    float spawnTimerMax;
    std::vector<Enemy*> enemies;

};

> Edit: **so Enemy.cpp is:**

#include "Enemy.h"

using namespace sf;

void Enemy::initTexture() {
    if (!this->texture.loadFromFile("textures/enemy1.png")) {
        std::cout << "ERROR::ENEMY::INITTEXTURE:: Could not load texture file!" << "\n";
    }
}

void Enemy::initSprite() {

    this->sprite.setTexture(this->texture);

    this->sprite.scale(1.1f, 1.1f);
}

void Enemy::initVariables() {
    this->type       = 0;
    this->hpMax      = 10;
    this->hp         = 0;
    this->damage     = 1;
    this->points     = 5;
}

Enemy::Enemy(float pos_x, float pos_y)
{
    this->initVariables();
    this->initTexture();
    this->initSprite();
}

Enemy::~Enemy()
{

}

void Enemy::update() {

}

void Enemy::render(RenderTarget& target) {
    target.draw(this->sprite);
}

**Enemy.h is:**

class Enemy
{
    private:
        Texture texture;
        Sprite sprite;
        int type;
        int hp;
        int hpMax;
        int damage;
        int points;

        void initTexture();
        void initSprite();
        void initVariables();

    public:
        Enemy(float pos_x, float pos_y);
        virtual ~Enemy();

        void update();
        void render(RenderTarget& target);
};


My crystal ball thinks that the problem is inside Enemy.

Probably it is. I added Enemy.cpp and Enemy.h to the question

I assume "this-\>" is a typo?

yeah, sorry, this is a stackoverflow thing

You're not actually using pos_x and pos_y inside Enemy::Enemy.

I added this->sprite.setPosition(pos_x, pos_y) and it worked as I wanted. Thx a lot.
